# Can gradient descent solve this problem $\text{argmin}_x \|Ax-[Var(Ax)]^{\frac{1}{2}}-b\|^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, least-squares

How can I find the (approximate) solution to the following problem:

$$\text{argmin}_x \|Ax-[Var(Ax)]^{\frac{1}{2}}-b\|^2,$$ where $Var(.)$ denotes the variance?
$A$ is matrix and $b$ and $x$ are vectors, and only $x$ is unknown.

EDIT: $$Var(A_ix)=\sqrt{\sum_jP(j|i)(A_jx-\sum_jP(j|i)A_jx)^2}$$

$A_i$ is the $i$-th row of $A$, $P$ is conditional probability mass function.

Comment: Is that component-wise variance and square-root?

Comment: @AlexR. Yes, it is.

Comment: Isn't the variance of a scalar just zero?

Comment: @MichaelGrant Suppose we approximate a random variable by $A_ix$, where $A_i$ is the $i$-th row of $A$. I can expand the $Var(A_ix)$ as $\sum_jP(j|i)(A_jx-\sum_jP(j|i)A_jx)^2$. $P$ denotes conditional probability mass function. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, thank you.